# Vue2 update parent scope from modal component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a modal component that takes some input, creates a record on the backend and then as part of the success response I would like to push data to an object on the parent scope.

I have tried emitting an event from the child on success with the data I would like to append but I can't seem to get it to fire.

When addNote() successfully completes what would be the best approach to update the "notes" array object on the parent scope with the data I get back in my component?

```
Vue.component('modal', {
    template: '#modal-template',
    data: function() {
        return {correctiveAction: this.correctiveAction}
    },
    props: ['notes'],
    methods: {
        addNote: function () {
            axios.get('/quality/ajax/add-note/', {
                params: {
                    action: this.correctiveAction
                }
            }).then(function (response) {
                // append new corrective action
                app = this;
                this.$emit('addingNote', response.data.data.success[0].data);
                //app.notes.push(response.data.data.success[0].data);
                swal({
                    title: "Boom!",
                    type: "success",
                    text: "Corrective Action Successfully Added",
                });
            }).catch()
        }
    }
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        segment: "",
        customer: "",
        product: "",
        startDate: "",
        endDate: "",
        notes: "",
        showModal: false,
        correctiveAction: ""

    },
    delimiters: ["<%","%>"],
    methods: {
        refresh: function () {
            location.reload();
        },
        getNotes: function () {
            app = this
            axios.get('/quality/ajax/get-notes/').then(function (response) {
                // populate notes
                app.notes = response.data.data.success[0].notes

            }).catch()
        },
        removeNote: function (id, index) {
            app = this
            axios.get('/quality/ajax/remove-note/', {
                params: {
                    id: id
                }
            }).then(function () {
                // remove note from list
                app.notes.splice(index, 1);
                swal({
                    title: "",
                    type: "success",
                    text: "Corrective Action Successfully Removed",
                });

            }).catch(function (err) {

                console.log(err)
                swal({
                    title: "",
                    type: "warning",
                    text: "Error Deleting Corrective Action",
                });
                return;

            });
        },
        generateReport: function () {

            $('#loading').show();



            }).catch()
        }
    }

});

// get all active corrective actions
app.getNotes();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for one, you are setting a global variable `app` as a result of `new Vue()` and then you are blowing that variable away in your `addNote` method by setting `app = this`. That changes the variable to a completely different thing.

Also, you don't show anything listening to the `addingNote` event.

Don't use app everywhere. Use a scoped variable.

```
getNotes: function () {
    const self = this
    axios.get('/quality/ajax/get-notes/').then(function (response) {
        // populate notes
        self.notes = response.data.data.success[0].notes
    }).catch()
},
```

And change addNote.

```
addNote: function () {
   const self = this
   axios.get('/quality/ajax/add-note/', {
       params: { action: this.correctiveAction}
   }).then(function (response) {
       // append new corrective action
       self.$emit('addingNote', response.data.data.success[0].data);
       swal({
           title: "Boom!",
           type: "success",
           text: "Corrective Action Successfully Added",
       });
   }).catch()
}
```

Looks like you should also fix `removeNote`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification especially around 'this', this worked like a charm,